# C conditional operator ('?') with empty second parameter

Tags: c, operators, conditional-statements, ternary-operator

Typically the '?' operator is used in the following form:

```
A ? B : C
```

However in cases where B = A I have seen the following abbreviation

```
A ? : C
```

This surprisingly works. Is it better to leave the second parameter in (style wise), or is their a chance certain compilers won't be able to handle this?

Comment: Looking like [Groovy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Groovy_%28programming_language%29)-like syntax.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

It is not permitted by the language C (as far as I know), but compilers such as gcc have the shortcut a?:c as an [extension](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.7.0/gcc/Conditionals.html#Conditionals).
`a?:c` means the same as `a?a:c`.

Comment: It means the same... with the caveat that `a` does not contain side-effects. `a?:c` only executes `a` once, whereas `a?a:c` would execute the side-effects of `a` twice.

Comment: It works for Clang too.

Answer (score 17):

Its a gcc's extension

[Conditionals with Omitted Operands](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Conditionals.html#Conditionals)

`x ? : y` is equivalent to `x ? x : y`

Comment: The page you linked to contradicts itself. On the one hand it says "This example is perfectly equivalent to `x ? x : y`", which means `x` is evaluated twice, but on the other hand the last paragraph states that `x` would be evaluated only once, which would make it perfectly equivalent to `x || y`, not `x ? x : y`

Comment: @Celada : I think it means to say that `x ?  : y` is **roughly** equivalent to `x ? x : y` except `x` gets evaluated only once in the former case.

Comment: @Celada : `x || y` evaluates to 0 or 1 which is not the case with this operator.

Comment: I stand corrected. I thought `||` returned value value of its first argument if the first argument was something that is considered true (nonzero).

Comment: It's one of ISO C99 features. It works fine for me on `GCC` 4.4.1<TDM-2 mingw32> and `TCC`(that's an ANSI C compiler) version 0.9.25 on Windows plataform.

Comment: It works for Clang too, not only GCC.

Answer (score 3):

Unless I'm badly mistake, you're using a compiler extension (at a guess, gcc). I'm pretty sure the standard does *not* allow you to omit the second operand to the ternary operator.

Answer (score 3):

I fill in a bit.

The standard uses the term ***conditional operator***.

```
Syntax
  conditional-expression:
          logical-OR-expression
          logical-OR-expression ? expression : conditional-expression
```

*A conditional expression does not yield an lvalue.* Also; [Wikipedia; Conditional](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_%28programming%29)

<sub>Note: I.e.: C++ has:

         logical-OR-expression ? expression : **assignment**-expression</sub>

```
Constraints:
* The first operand shall have scalar type[1].
* One of the following shall hold for the second and third operands:
   — both operands have arithmetic type[2];
   — both operands have the same structure[3] or union type[4];
   — both operands have void type[5];
   — both operands are pointers to qualified or unqualified[6] versions of compatible
     types[7];
   — one operand is a pointer and the other is a null pointer constant[8]; or
   — one operand is a pointer to an object or incomplete type[9] and the other 
     is a pointer to a qualified or unqualified version of void.
```

Foot food:

```
[1] Scalar type     : Arithmetic types and pointer types.
[2] Arithmetic type : Integer and floating types.
[3] Structure type  : A sequentially allocated nonempty set of member objects (and, in
                     certain circumstances, an incomplete array), each of which has an
                     optionally specified name and possibly distinct type.
[4] Union type      : An overlapping nonempty set of member objects, each of which has
                     an optionally specified name and possibly distinct type.
[5] Void type       : An empty set of values; it is an incomplete type that cannot be
                     completed.
[6] Qualified type  : 1998 (const and volatile), 1999 (restrict), respectively 
                     2011 (_Atomic). *
[7] Compatible type : Their types are the same.
[8] Null ptr. const.: NULL; implementation-defined null pointer constant.
[9] Incomplete type : Types that describe objects but lack information needed to determine 
                      their sizes.
```

<sup>*</sup> [Type qualifiers in C](http://www.bezem.de/pdf/tqinc.pdf)

So: Not wise to use.

Answer (score 1):

i did a little research in the web, acording to wikipedia, this behavior is supported by a GNU extension of C. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%3F:#C

So it is very probable that other compilers consider this illegal. By the way, this operator is called ternary conditional so you can browse about it.

EDIT:

I checked in gcc and apple llvm and it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

It is better to leave the second parameter in. If B ever changes, you may not remember to modify the statement above. Further, other people may have a difficult time reading your code and improving upon it if you leave B out of the statement.