# Bitwise and/or with ternary operator

Tags: c++, bitwise-operators, ternary-operator, logical-operators, logical-or

Look at this tiny snippet.

```
y<v|!v?:y=v;
```

(`y` is minimum value, and `v` is current compared value. This way would make you think easier.)

This snippet’s meaning is simple. 
If current value `v` is smaller then minimum value `y`, set new minimum value(`y=v`). But `v=0` case is excluded.

Then I thought if the 'adverse code' could be generated, the result should be same. I mean,

```
y>v&v?y=v:;
```

This code should do same thing. But it cannot be compiled. The error is as follows.

```
error: expected expression
  for(int v: a) v=abs(a[i]-v), x>v?:x=v, y>v&v?y=v:;
                                                   ^
```

It’s weird. I think two codes are same each other. If latter ternary operator is erroneous, former should have same problem. But it didn’t.

Can someone explain why?

Next question.
I inserted a `0` to compile. `y>v&v?y=v:0;`
Then I got a false answer.
So I changed `&` to `&&`. `y>v&&v?y=v:0;` 
Finally I got a right answer. But without these process, using `|` operator can do all. Why?

<additional info>

My compiler version is as follows.

```
$ gcc --version
Configured with: --prefix=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr --with-gxx-include-dir=/usr/include/c++/4.2.1
Apple LLVM version 6.1.0 (clang-602.0.53) (based on LLVM 3.6.0svn)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin14.4.0
Thread model: posix
```

And compile option:

```
g++ -std=c++11 my.cpp
```

If you want to have a sample code to test, this would help.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;
int working(int i, vector<int> a) {
  int y=INT_MAX;
  for(int v: a) v=abs(a[i]-v), y<v|!v?:y=v;
  return y;
}

int not_working(int i, vector<int> a) {
  int y=INT_MAX;
  for(int v: a) v=abs(a[i]-v), y>v&v?y=v:0;
  return y;
}

int main() {
  vector<int> b({-5,-2,2,7});
  cout << working(2, b) << endl;
  cout << not_working(2,b) << endl;
  return 0;
}
```

*(p.s. correction of my poor english is always welcomed)*

Comment: @YuHao These are all just for fun. I know readability is very very  important. :)

Comment: [C++ Operator Precedence](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence)

Comment: `: nothing` doesn't make sense. you need a value for the ternary operator.

Comment: What does this question have to do with operator precedence?

Comment: @CoryKramer I saw that page. and I was not able to get any good clue to answer this question.

Comment: @KarolyHorvath right. Then former code should not be compiled. But it works! :-o

Comment: @Barry good point. please suggest any other title. I think precedence may not give any help now.

Comment: Compile with `-std=c++11 -Wall -Wextra -pedantic` and you'll get `warning: ISO C++ does not allow ?: with omitted middle operand [-Wpedantic]` and a few other helpful warnings related to operator precedence. Similarly from Clang, with even more helpful warnings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this snippet:

```
y<v|!v?:y=v;
```

the value of `v` is converted to a `bool` and negated with `!`. Because both sides of the bitwise or `|` are bools, `|` behaves like the logical or.

In the other case:

```
y>v&v?y=v:0;
```

there is no conversion to `bool`, and instead the result of `y>v` is converted to `int`. The bitwise and `&` gives varying results, depending on the lowest bit of `v`. It does not behave like the logical and.
This should work like the original:

```
y>v&!!v?y=v:0;
```

because there is a conversion to bool.

Answer (score 4):

The codes do not do the same thing, because the conditions are not the negation of each other. Try it with `y == 3, v == 2`:

`y < v | !v` => `3 < 2 | !2` => `false | !true` => `false | false` => `0 | 0` => `0`

`y > v & v` => `3 > 2 & 2` => `true & 2` => `1 & 2` => `0`

Answer (score 2):

The syntax of the conditional operator is:

*logical-expression ? true-expression : false-expression*

In the first one,

```
y<v|!v ? : y=v;
```

you are missing *true-expression*. I get the following compiler warning with g++ when compiled with `-Wall`.

```
socc.cc: In function ‘int main()’:
socc.cc:14:12: warning: the omitted middle operand in ?: will always be ‘true’, suggest explicit middle operand [-Wparentheses]
    y<v||!v?:y=v;
```

In the second one,

```
y>v&v ? y=v : ;
```

You are missing *false-expression*. For some reason, g++ treats this as an error instead of a warning.

You could fix that by providing a dummy value for both of them.

By the way, you are using bitwise operators `|` and `&`. I am sure that is a small error.

You can use:

```
(y<v || !v) ?  0 : y=v;
```

or

```
(y>v && v) ? y=v : 0;
```

**Update**

The expression

```
(y<v || !v) ? : y=v;
```

is not legal C/C++. It is supported by g++ as an extension. More can be seen at [C conditional operator ('?') with empty second parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10143125/c-conditional-operator-with-empty-second-parameter).

Comment: Wow. This is gcc extension. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10143125/c-conditional-operator-with-empty-second-parameter
thank you!